# Inject <link> and <script> in webview

Tags: android

```
    @Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    view.loadUrl("javascript: function(){" +
                    "var newlink = document.createElement('link');" +
                    "newlink.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');" +
                    "newlink.setAttribute('href', 'http://maven.com/slide/caca.css');" +
                    "document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(newlink);" +
                    "}");

}
```

But the thing won't run ok. I was expecting for the webview to download the CSS and set in to the page.

Basically I want to add remote CSS and JS files to a webview.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this? I really don't want to manually download the content of the files, cache them or whatnot, and then set them in the webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this works. Not entirely sure why though ...

```
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "

            + "var script=document.createElement('link'); "
            + " script.setAttribute('type','text/css'); "
            + " script.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet'); "
            + " script.setAttribute('href', 'http://maven.com/slide/caca.css'); "
            + "document.head.appendChild(script); "

            + "})();");
```

Anyway ... 7 hours right down the drain ...